# SAPUI5 OData V4 Read

Tags: odata, sapui5, odata-v4

Can you please tell how to perform OData Read in OData V4 in SAPUI5 ?

I can do this very easily in OData V2, how do I achieve similar things with oData V4 ?

```
this_.getOwnerComponent().getModel("myModel").read("/zprojects", {
                "async": true,
                "success": function (oData) {
                    console.log(oData);
                },
                "error": function (oError) {
                    console.log(oError);
                }
            });
```

The problem for me is I want to massage the data to add additional values before I bind to view. Here is my complete code of oData V2:

```
this_.getOwnerComponent().getModel("myModel").read("/zprojects", {
                "async": true,
                "success": function (oData) {
                    var myArray = [];
                    var pos;

                    for (var i = 0; i < oData.results.length; i++) {
                        pos = myArray.map(function (e) {
                            return e.ID;
                        }).indexOf(oData.results[i].PROJECTID);
                        if (pos === -1) {
                            myArray.push({
                                ID: oData.results[i].PROJECTID,
                                PROJECT_DESC: oData.results[i].PROJECT_DESC
                            });
                        }
                    }
                    myArray.sort((a, b) => (a.PROJECT_DESC > b.PROJECT_DESC) ? 1 : -1);
                    myArray.unshift({
                        ID: "-1",
                        PROJECT_DESC: "Please select Project ID"
                    oModel = new sap.ui.model.json.JSONModel(myArray);
                    sap.ui.core.Fragment.byId("idFragment", "project").setModel(oModel);
                },
                "error": function (oError) {
                    console.log(oError);
                }
            });
```

Comment: have you already looked at the provided tutorial from the demokit? https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/#/topic/bcdbde6911bd4fc68fd435cf8e306ed0

Comment: I read that, but I am not sure how do I process my data before I bind to idFragment. Any code example?

Comment: @user9550188 What are the requirements that you feel the need to "process" the data and throw away the whole ODataModel bindings in favor of JSONModel which is a clientside model? From the code you provided, looks like the only requirement is to show _`Please select Project ID`_ as the first Select(?) item. Is that it?

Comment: The requirement is to populate the list of values on top of the "Please select Project ID". So it is drop down list with selection option with values.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the [documentation](https://help.sap.com/doc/saphelp_uiaddon20/2.05/en-US/96/13f1f2d88747cab21896f7216afdac/content.htm?no_cache=true):

> The OData V4 model only supports data access using bindings. It does not provide any direct access to the data.

You can get around that by creating fake bindings and listening to the `dataReceived` event, but I'd rather suggest using [jQuery's ajax features](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/) to request the data, until the `v4.ODataModel` supports direct access to the data:

```
$.get({
    url: "<your_service_url>/zprojects",
    success: function(data) {
        // your success logic
    },
    error: function(error) {
        // your error logic
    }
});
```

Comment: I don't think `v4.ODataModel` will ever support direct read API as it often leads to anti-patterns (e.g. mixing UI data with business data). I'm quite happy they decided not to support manual `read`.